# How to find the missing months from a list of months within a year

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have the example list of sales below showing how much money was made for last 12 months with 2 months missing (Can be more or less).

```
[{1, 400}, {2,500}, {4, 550}, {5, 425}, {6, 770}, {7, 500}, {9, 300}, {10, 900}, {11, 440}, {12, 620}]
```

The months are in ascending order so 1 is Jan and 12 is Dec. How can I update this list in code to add a sales object for the missing months with value of 0. In this case adding `{3, 0}` and `{8, 0}`.

I retrieve these from the database and the reason some are missing is because they do not have a record in the database, so I want to add zero for the missing months. The month comes from `DateTime.Date.Month`.

Comment: Please show us the variable and the structure your saving this month list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a class representing your months:

```
public class MonthData
{
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Money { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use LINQ to find the missing months, then insert them into the original list:

```
var months = new List<MonthData>
{
    new MonthData {Month = 1, Money = 400},
    new MonthData {Month = 2, Money = 500},
    new MonthData {Month = 4, Money = 550},
    new MonthData {Month = 5, Money = 425},
    new MonthData {Month = 6, Money = 770},
    new MonthData {Month = 7, Money = 500},
    new MonthData {Month = 9, Money = 300},
    new MonthData {Month = 10, Money = 900},
    new MonthData {Month = 11, Money = 440},
    new MonthData {Month = 12, Money = 620}
};

# Find missing months
var missingMonths = Enumerable
    .Range(months.Min(m => m.Month), months.Max(m => m.Month))
    .Except(months.Select(m => m.Month))

# Insert missing months back into months list
foreach (var month in missingMonths)
{
    months.Insert(month - 1, new MonthData { Month = month, Money = 0 });
}
```

Additionally, [`List<T>.Insert(Int32, T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netframework-4.8) is **O(N)** for insertion. We can improve this by using a `Dictionary<int, int>` for **O(1)** insertion:

```
var months = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
    {1, 400},
    {2,500},
    {4, 550},
    {5, 425},
    {6, 770},
    {7, 500},
    {9, 300},
    {10, 900},
    {11, 440},
    {12, 620}
};

var missingMonths = Enumerable
    .Range(months.Keys.Min(), months.Keys.Max())
    .Except(months.Keys);

foreach (var month in missingMonths)
{
    months[month] = 0;
}
```

And also has the option to go back to a `List<MonthData>` down the line:

```
var monthList = months
    .Select(pair => new MonthData { 
        Month = pair.Key, 
        Money = pair.Value 
    })
    .OrderBy(m => m.Month)
    .ToList();
```

Which requires **O(NLogN)** sorting with [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8), since dictionaries are unordered in nature.

Try on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m5NyLW)

Comment: Won't this code fail if January is one of the missing months?

Answer (score 2):

Tried to do it as closes to your model as possible

```
// Example
var yearSales = new Dictionary<int, decimal>
{
    {  1, 100 },
    {  3, 300 },
    {  6, 600 },
};

// Actual logic
var fullMonths = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
    .ToDictionary(
        month => month,
        month => yearSales.TryGetValue(month, out decimal d) ? d : default
    );
```